# variable loads me undefined reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a session variable `user?.id` that only loads after having loaded the project, it means that the first time it loads it shows as undefined and after reloading the project it loads me with the corresponding value but it is causing an error in my `GET` in axios because when loading it the first time it detects it as undefined and that triggers a series of errors and my `GET` does not load, I have tried to solve it but I have not been able to achieve it.

```js
 import React, {useContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
    import {MyContext} from '../../login/MyContext'

    import axios from 'axios';

    function Perfil() {

        const {user} = useContext(MyContext); 
      
      const [data, setData]=useState([]);
        
     
        const peticionGet =async() =>{
                   
            await axios.get(`https://aliraweb.com/apiAliraweb/perfil_img/index.php?id_p=${user?.id}`) //LOADS ME UNDEFINED "user?.id"
            .then(response=>{
             setData(response.data);
            }).catch(error=>{
              console.log(error);
            })
        
          }


      useEffect(()=>{
        const interval = setInterval(() => {  
           
           peticionGet();
           
         }, 2000);
       return () => setInterval(interval); 
       },[])

         
      
    if(user)
        {
      return (
     
    <div>
    {console.log("HERE LOADS THE VARIABLE WITHOUT PROBLEMS " + user?.id)}
    </div>

    </div>
       
      )
    }

    else if(!user){
        return"";
    }

    }

    export default Perfil
```

Comment: If it was helpful, do you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple fix.

1. Check if `user.id` is set in the useEffect. If not, return.
2. Add the `user` object to the dependency array of useEffect to re-trigger, whenever `user` changes

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!user?.id) return
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        peticionGet();

    }, 2000);
    return () => setInterval(interval);
}, [user])
```